# Angular Refresh Error - The server encountered an internal error when I refresh Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, api

Each time I tried to refresh my Angular Page or click on refresh button, I got this error:

[image: angular refresh error page]

Then when I console it, I got this:

[image: Angular console error]

When the application was on my local system it wasn't like that. It started on the server.

Please what do I do

Comment: You need to be more specific, show the error, show how you configured stuff, what you tried so far - otherwise it is not possible to help you there. Good luck!

Comment: I already show the screenshot of the error. Also, I inspect the page and got the second sreenshot I showed (In red colour.). What do you mean by:   show how you configured stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check, above you rootfolder/src/index.html   
1 ) if do you have permision, +wx is correct if not, apply correct permissions for this project Execute and write or administrator +rwx

2 )  check if don't exist some errors on rootfolder/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

with the modules and components correctly imported
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

and get services correctly
Example for services end points for angular from laravel.

API_URI =  'http://localhost:3001/endpoint__api';

```
export class GnomesService {

gnome: Gnomes = {
  name: '',
  thumbnail: '',
  age:'',
  weight: '',
  height: '',
  hair_color: '',
  professions: '',
  friends:'',
  created_at: new Date()
};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getGnomes() {

  return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/gnomes`);
}

getGnome(id: string) {
  return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/gnomes/${id}`);
}

deleteGnomes(id: string) {
  return this.http.delete(`${this.API_URI}/gnomes/${id}`);
}

saveGnome(gnome: Gnomes) {
  return this.http.post(`${this.API_URI}/gnomes`, gnome);
}

updateGnome(id: string|number, updatedGnome: Gnomes) {
return this.http.put(`${this.API_URI}/gnomes/${id}`, updatedGnome);
}

}
```

Example for rootfolder/src/app.routing-module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/gnomes',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'gnomes',
        component: GnomesListComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'gnomes/add',
        component: GnomesFormComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'gnomes/edit/:id',
        component: GnomesFormComponent
      }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you building an new project on angular? executing dist/index.html folder on laravel do you get routes / end point to angular? exist dist folder foward you build this project?

Comment: Yes. Am building new project on angular. Angular points to endpoints from Laravel. Please what do you mean by:  "exist dist folder foward you build this project"

Comment: when you run the command ng build this create automatically the dist folder on proyect. with http-server you can run the bundle files